# AngularJS ngRoute Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I'm attempting to build a simple "login" app in order to get a start in AngularJS, and I'm following a guide on this. It has mentioned that I should add "ngRoute" as a dependency to my app, which I have done, and I included the CDN for the angular-route.js file in my code as well, but no matter what I try, I receive the following error:

```
angular.js:38Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/$injector/modulerr?p0=loginApp&p1=Referen…googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.1%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A1)
at angular.js:38
at angular.js:4759
at q (angular.js:357)
at g (angular.js:4720)
at eb (angular.js:4642)
at c (angular.js:1838)
at Mc (angular.js:1859)
at pe (angular.js:1744)
at angular.js:32977
at HTMLDocument.b (angular.js:3314)
```

Here's my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-route.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="script/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="script/controllers/controllers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="script/service/services.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div ng-app="loginApp">
    <div ng-view></div>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="loginView.html">
        <div>
            <input type="text" ng-model="username" /><br />
            <input type="password" ng-model="password" /><br />
            <input type="button" value="Submit" ng-click="submitCredentials()" /><br />
        </div>
    </script>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="successView.html">
        <div>
            <p>
                Success! You logged in!
            </p>
        </div>
    </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my app.js:

```
"use strict";

angular.module("loginApp", ['ngRoute'])
.run(function($state, LoginService) {
if(!LoginService.isAuthenticated()) {
    $state.transitionTo('login');
}
})
.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/success');

$routeProvider.
when('/login', {
    templateUrl: 'loginView.html',
    controller: 'loginCtrl'
}).
when('/success', {
    templateUrl: 'successView.html',
    controller: 'successCtrl'
}).
otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/login'
});
}]);
```

And I believe that's all the relevant code. If anything more is required, please do not hesitate to request it.

***EDIT 1***

I'm sorry, I forgot to delete the urlRouterProvider and the state thing. It's working fine now. Thank you all.

Comment: Try removing "use strict" temporarily. Module error can also be caused by syntax problems so make sure your code is lint free. Are you sure you haven't declared any module more that once also...can be common mistake

Comment: I added "use strict" after the error started happening, so it can't be that. What does "lint free" mean? And no, I haven't declared the module more than once.

Comment: lint free ...meaning run it through a code linter either in an IDE or online if your IDE doesn't have that feature